# jquery plugin issue with adding strong tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating simple jquery plugin with simple code to make text bold:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.green = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var markup = $this.html();
            markup = $.fn.green.format(markup);
            $this.html(markup);
        });
    };
    $.fn.green.format = function(txt) {
        return "<strong>" + txt + "<strong>";
    };
}(jQuery));
```

the output is:

```
<div>
    <strong>this is quotation<strong>
    </strong></strong>
</div>
```

This adds one extra strong tag in div.
Can you tell me what is the issue with this code.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `<strong>` tag be a closing tag?  `</strong>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your below code:

```
return "<strong>" + txt + "<strong>";
```

With the following:

```
return "<strong>" + txt + "</strong>";
```

As your in the code strong tag is not closed so HTML is making a extra strong tag to close it.